# IntentService, PendingIntent, and AlarmManager: Cannot keep process running indefinitely?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent, locationmanager, intentservice

I've got a pretty simple app that runs two services in the background, using IntentService with AlarmManager. One is a "messaging" service that sends a JSON request and parses the response, the other polls for location from a LocationManager. The requirement here is that they run on an interval, indefinitely, until manually stopped by the user, with a button - even if the device's screen hasn't been turned on for days. The services must never stop. Battery life is not a concern.

My minimum-supported API is 4.1 and I'm testing on 4.1, 4.2, and 4.4 devices. On my Nexus 7 and GPad, 4.4.4 and 4.4.2, respectively, the services will run indefinitely and work as expected. On a Galaxy Tab 3 running 4.2, the device seemed to go to sleep after 8 hrs. or so of inactivity, and would then quit reporting location and polling. The 4.1 devices seem to do the same.

With that hunch, I added this to the messaging service to manually wake the CPU. This one runs every 60 sec. so I had hoped it would prevent the devices from ever going to sleep.

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent)
{                       
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(
            PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, 
            "com.service.MESSAGE_SERVICE_WAKE_LOCK");

    wl.acquire();

    //poll for messages via JSON    

    wl.release();               
}
```

Setting the AlarmManager like so (pi = PendingIntent...passing in the IntentService class):

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), pollInterval, pi);
```

This appeared to fix things for my own testing, and the devices are consistently reporting location for me on 4.4 and 4.2. However, the 4.1 testers have reported that it still goes to sleep on them after about 8 hrs. I also tested it on a friend's Galaxy S5 (4.4.2) and it quit reporting location after a few hours.

This is my first app and this part has been especially frustrating. Am I doing something wrong? Any idea why these services might stop running? Happy to provide more code if that helps...thought I'd start with this, at least.

Comment: "The requirement here is that they run until manually stopped" -- please define "run" and "manually stopped". Do you actually mean "the requirement here is that the alarms keep firing and the services get their chance to do their work until manually stopped"? That would be reasonable and your problems would be fixable.

Comment: The services must run without interruption, in the background, at all times. I also need the ability to shut them down manually from an Activity. I don't care how it's done, just need to get there.

Comment: "The services must run without interruption, in the background, at all times" -- that's not what you wrote in your code, and what you want is not strictly possible. That is why I asked if my rephrasing of your "requirement" accurately reflects what you need. There is a **massive** difference between "alarms keep firing and the services get their chance to do their work" and "services must run without interruption".

Comment: Alright, sorry if I wasn't entirely clear. So, running a background service indefinitely, in Android, is not possible. Correct?

Comment: The user can get rid of a background service whenever the user wants. Of course, the user can also get rid of your alarms too, but that's somewhat less likely. The OS will terminate your process too, due to low memory conditions, and that's another benefit of going the route of simply stating that your services need to run in response to `AlarmManager` events, as once those services are done with their work, it doesn't matter if the process gets terminated.

Comment: OK, thanks. I'm not entirely clear on how that's done - like I said, it's my first app. Android is entirely new to me. Do you have a clear example? Is this the same thing Larry is talking about below?

Comment: "Do you have a clear example?" -- I have [a whole chapter](http://commonsware.com/Android) on `AlarmManager`, including a few samples, such as [this one](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/AlarmManager/WakeCast). What Larry is discussing is spot-on, now that I have confirmed that this is pretty much the behavior you want.

Comment: CommonsWare - I followed your example, linked above. It seems to make sense. I call "scheduleAlarms" from my Activity, which should set the WakefulBroadcastReceiver to run on a schedule - just like I was doing with my PendingIntent directly, prior. However, onReceive never gets called. I copied yours exactly, but lowered the PERIOD to 10 seconds. I'm very much a noob here...not sure what I could be missing.

Comment: Did you register the receiver in the manifest? Does LogCat show anything of note?

Comment: Ha! Yes...that was all. Forgot to add to add it to the manifest. It's working! Now I just need to run it for a couple days and see if it actually keeps the device awake. Thanks so much for your help! Example code was great!

Comment: One more quick question: Calling PendingIntent.cancel() and AlarmManager.cancel() is how I'd manually stop the polling, correct? I need a way for the user to shut this off.

Comment: I'd go with `cancel()` on `AlarmManager`. You should not need both.

Answer (score 3):

Alarms which use `PendingIntent` for a `Service` are not guaranteed to keep the device awake long enough for the `Service` to be started or resumed.  In the case of an `IntentService`, the service automatically dies once it has processed all queued `Intent` objects.  You'll need to use a `PendingIntent` for a `BroadcastReceiver` which takes a `WakeLock` and starts your `Service`.  Your `Service` can then release the wakelock when it is done with its work, allowing the device to go back to sleep.

Comment: Do you have a clear example for this? I am indeed sending an Intent to a BroadcastReceiver, every time onHandleIntent is called, in my code above. Anyhow, would love to see a simple code example of what you're describing. Thanks.

Comment: You're in luck, I've written an article on this before and included a simple test app to show it. http://po.st/7UpipA

Comment: "which takes a WakeLock and starts your Service. Your Service can then release the wakelock when it is done with its work" -- the simplest way to implement this is to use a canned solution, [such as `WakefulBroadcastReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html).

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` was created to do.  In the sample code from my article I took a slightly different approach, placing the wakelock in the `Application` class for the app; but, the end result is the same.

Comment: Interesting, I'll look into WakefulBroadcastReceiver. Thank you both for the help.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish for a service to "always" run, you shouldn't make is a background service.

Make it a [**foreground service**](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground) instead:

> A foreground service is a service that's considered to be something
>   the user is actively aware of and thus not a candidate for the system
>   to kill when low on memory.

In order to try out how long your service can run when the OS has low RAM, you can try [**this sample**](https://android-developer-preview.googlecode.com/issues/attachment?aid=15190000000&name=MemoryConsumerTest.7z&token=ABZ6GAfPN6MU4YE2FNmrTY8ZaXBlCCCUHg%3A1418072336726) I've made (which I've posted [**here**](https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=1519), and uses [**this library**](https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/AndroidJniBitmapOperations) I've made), which uses more and more RAM (real RAM, not of the heap). It causes the OS to kill other processes and eventually kill the process of the sample itself.

If you just want your services to run every X hours/minutes, you don't need this at all, and what you've found seems ok.

Comment: That's an interesting approach. It's safe for network (i.e. JSON requests) and LocationManager? Those are the two features I use the most in this app. The "this sample" link is broken...would love to get a look at it if you fix it, however. Thanks!

Comment: You are correct. The link doesn't work for some reason, but the post is OK. go to the post and download it there. it's called "MemoryConsumerTest.7z" . The sample only tries to stress the OS, so you could see what will happen to your service and handle it accordingly. About safety, it's safe for using a foreground service for what you wrote, but you will still need to handle cases that the service is killed for any reason (too low memory).

Comment: Only have a service running when it actively delivers value to the user: http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/27/role-services.html

Comment: @CommonsWare Well it also depends on what the service is doing. I don't know for sure what he tries to do. That said, you are correct. I hope he understands what it means that his service will run in the foreground, by reading the link I've provided.