# PendingIntent with IntentService not working

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent, intentservice, android-alarms

Following code works perfectly for `Activity`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
PendingIntent operation = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 
                              0, 
                              intent, 
                              PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
alarmmanager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 
                              startTime.getTimeInMillis(),
                              operation);
```

However, when I do the same thing for `IntentService`, It works only if  `startTime` and time I set alarm are on the same day. e.g. If I set the alarm today for 5 PM, it will be executed but when I set the alarm today for 5 PM tomorrow, it will not be executed. If this was `Activity` then it works for both cases.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
PendingIntent operation = PendingIntent.getService(context, 
                              0, 
                              intent, 
                              PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
alarmmanager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 
                              startTime.getTimeInMillis(),
                              operation);
```

How to solve this?

The goal here I am trying to achieve is to execute `IntentService` every day at the exact time.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27365381/intentservice-pendingintent-and-alarmmanager-cannot-keep-process-running-inde

Comment: What is your target SDK? What device are you testing on? Was the device awake when the alarm should have gone off?

Comment: TargetSDK is 27. Testing on API 27 Official Emulator. Yes, the device was awake.

Comment: Can you try to set target SDK to 25 and see if this behaves differently?

Comment: You could also try using `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle()` instead of `setExact()` to see if that changes the behaviour on SDK 27.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The goal here I am trying to achieve is to execute IntentService every day at the exact time.

Google has made this progressively harder from release to release. See [Android AlarmManager setExact() is not exact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38094420/android-alarmmanager-setexact-is-not-exact). There could be two ways to solve this for your case:

1. you start an activity, which starts the service (as starting an Activity seems to work for you)
2. you use either [`setExactAnd...`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager#setexactandallowwhileidle) or [`setAlarmClock`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setalarmclock). `setAlarmClock` also triggers in the new "doze" mode, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/47049705/1587329.

Another way would be to re-think why and if you really need this... or if a JobScheduler could not fit your purpose more easily.

Answer (score 0):

add replace your line with this line :

```
alarmmanager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 
                          startTime.getTimeInMillis(),
                          operation);
```

it will repeat on specific interval you set in alarm manager

Comment: as of API 19 all repeating alarms are inexact. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager#setRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)

Comment: yeah i know. then you should to change your flow for setting alarm.
when the first time alarm ring, again set alarm after getting the current time. By putting same requestcode in alarmmanager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 
                              startTime.getTimeInMillis(),
                              operation);

Comment: I have done the same but It works correctly only when PendingIntent is Activity. It does not work for IntentService.

Comment: then do try with BroadcastReceiver instead of intentService. because i have done same for my project with BroadcastReceiver. and its working fine @AksharPatel

Answer (score 0):

HERE IS a DETAILED ANSWER check link in the bottom for more details.
Hope this will help. Your issue can be probably related to android versions too so do check the link for more details

app gets an instance of the AlarmManager and sets an alarm using a PendingIntent. More on usage and setting alarms is coming in the next section. The AlarmManager is the app side interface to the backing AlarmManagerService. It abstracts the details of the Binder interface, used to communicate with the system process (system_server) hosting the AlarmManagerService. These two components manage the alarm(s) the app has set and will send the PendingIntent correctly. This manager/service architecture is used throughout Android framework and is done for security and isolation purposes. The system_server process is running with privileges which normal apps do not have. If you are unfamiliar with Android’s use of permissions, see this article for more details on app processes and user IDs. These extra permissions are what allows system_server to access the underlying kernel alarm driver. The alarm driver is what manages setting alarms to wake up the device regardless of the sleep state of the SoC.

When the alarm is triggered the device is awakened (if asleep) and the AlarmManagerService is notified of an alarm expiring. It will then send the PendingIntent accordingly. This will cause the appropriate component within MyApp to be activated. If MyApp has not been started or its process is not cached, it will be started so the component can be activated.

**basic usage will be as**

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
...
private AlarmManager  mAlarmMgr;
...
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
    ...
    mAlarmMgr = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    ...
}
...


}
```

**let’s create a PendingIntent for our MyActivity using the component name**.

```
Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
PendingIntent pend = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
                              0,
                              alarmIntent,
                              PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Now that we have our PendingIntent and the AlarmManager, we can set our alarm so our Activity is triggered when the alarm has expired. To do this, we need to figure out when we want our alarm to go off and whether it should wake up the device or just be delivered the next time the device is awakened. Remember, we have two different ways of specifying time for our alarms: elapsed time or calendar (RTC) time. So our options are ELAPSED_REALTIME, ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, RTC or RTC_WAKEUP. The _WAKEUP variants are our “aggressive” alarms where we want the device to come out of low power to call our app back. For our sample app, let’s set this up in a custom BroadcastReceiver and have it trigger our Activity about 30 seconds after the device is booted

```
public class MyBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
public void onReceive(Context, context, Intent intent) {
    ...
    AlarmManager alarmMgr =
        (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    long wakeTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 30000;
    alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, wakeTime, pend);
}
}
```

Now when our device boots and the BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast is sent, our app’s process will be started and our receiver will set an alarm to trigger our Activity to be launched about 30 seconds later. Note that on Android 3.1 devices or newer, you must first manually launch your app before the BOOT_COMPLETED.

CREDIT GOES to writer of this [**BLOG**](http://hiqes.com/android-alarm-ins-outs/?utm_source=Direct)

if you want to set the repeated alarm using SetExact you are bound to stop all other pending intents on the same time check this [link](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=android.app.AlarmManager&method=setExact) for that here are many examples of how to do it!  again credit goes to this writer

Comment: Thanks for the descriptive answer. I have done the same but It works correctly only when PendingIntent is Activity. It does not work for IntentService.

Comment: Also set() method is inexact as of API 19. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager#set(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)

Comment: @AksharPatel man maybe you could use calendar details like it has said on this Daily Reminder thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12208008/how-to-create-a-reminder-notification

Comment: It uses setRepeating(). setRepeatig() works for me but I have to use only setExact() as setRepeating() is not exact.

Comment: https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=android.app.AlarmManager&method=setExact.    check the example 16th on this blog!

Answer (score 0):

Replace the AlarmManager with this code:

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, 
                          timeMills, 
                          AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, 
                          pendingIntent);
```

Worked for me.

Comment: as of API 19, all repeating alarms are inexact. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager#setRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)